# Create JSON object from a path and template

Tags: javascript

I'm a lazy coder by nature, so would like to know that there's a lib out there that does the following before I write on:

```
var parser = PathParser('/{first}/{last}');
var actual = parser.parse('/fred/flintstone');
assertEquals({"first":"fred","last":"flintstone"}, actual);
```

The first string specifies a pattern, and the second extracts the relevant values and stores them in an object with keys corresponding to those in the pattern.

I've found the standard that does the expansion, but not the generation of the JSON Object.

Comment: You might also want to explain in words what is going on here.

Comment: Which language is this? Some alternative to [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: You supply a template, with keys delimited by "{}".  This will make a JSON object from a path string, using the templated keys as the key in the object for the values.
Jersey does the same in Java with annotations for parsing values from a path.

Comment: Hmm like this?
JSON.parse("{"+"\"first\":\""+a.substring(0,a.indexOf("/"))+"\",\"last\":\""+a.substring(a.indexOf("/")+1)+"\"}");
Provided a = 'fred/flinstone'

Comment: That would work for the example given. What I'm looking for is a lib that parses based on a template.  I'm looking for something that would do the opposite of http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/, which merges a JSON Object with a temlate to make a uri

Comment: I think your question is valid, and I've added a tentative explanation to help ward off close votes. Please feel free to correct it if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract an array of keys from your first string and extract an array of values from the latter, where the value is preceded by a certain pattern and followed by a certain pattern.

There isn't an existing library that does this, but I have written an implementation. You can find a live demonstration [here](http://jsbin.com/unomof/1/edit).

```
//## Extension to escape all regex special characters in a string ##

RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};


//## Parsing ##

var parser = PathParser('/{first}/{last}');
var actual = parser('/fred/flintstone');


//## Output ##

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(actual, null, "  ");
document.body.appendChild(pre);    


//## The parser constructor ##

function PathParser(pattern) {
    var keys = [];
    var keyreg = /\{([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}/g;
    var result;
    while ((result = keyreg.exec(pattern)) !== null) {
        var pre = "^" + RegExp.quote(pattern.substring(0, result.index)).replace(/\\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\\}/g, ".*");
        var post = RegExp.quote(pattern.substring(keyreg.lastIndex)).replace(/\\\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\\}/g, ".*") + "$";
        keys.push({
            pre: pre,
            post: post,
            text: result[1]
        });
    }

    function parser(valstring) {
        var keyarr = keys;
        var obj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < keyarr.length; i++) {
            var valreg = new RegExp(keyarr[i].pre + "(.*)" + keyarr[i].post);
            obj[keyarr[i].text] = valstring.match(valreg)[1];
        }
        return obj;
    }

    return parser;
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the effort, and will give 'the big green tick' on that.  One thing that's a bit odd is '/mr/fred/flintstone' produces { 'first':'mr/fred', 'last':'flintstone' }.
I think that's because of my 'too loose' spec.  Thanks a lot for the effort.  That'll get me there, and I'll change as appropriate.

Comment: @BenHoskins That's because it'll try to find a match any way it can. If you change the pattern to `/{first}/{second}/{last}` this should get split up correctly. What was your expected result with `/mr/fred/flintstone`?